# Is there a closed form expression for the following definite integrals?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals, closed-form

I am looking for a closed form for these two integrals

$$\int_{-\infty}^{-a}\text{d}x \frac{1}{|x|}e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2\sigma^2}e^{i k |x|}+\int_a^{\infty}\text{d}x \frac{1}{|x|}e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2\sigma^2}e^{i k |x|}$$
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\text{d}xJ_0(k\,x)e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2\sigma^2}e^{-i k x}$$

where $a>0$, $\sigma>0$ and $k\geq0$, and $J_0(x)$ is the Bessel function of first kind.

Is it possible to find a closed form for them? Any help with how to obtain the expressions or simply the final answer would be highly appreciated. Even insight for the indefinite integrals would be useful.

**EDIT**: thanks to @Yuriy's advice, the second integral is

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\text{d}xJ_0(k\,x)e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2\sigma^2}e^{-i k x}=\frac{1}{2\sigma ^2}\left[\sqrt{2 \pi } \sigma  \, _2F_2\left(\frac{1}{4},\frac{3}{4};\frac{1}{2},1;-\frac{2 k^2}{\sigma ^2}\right)-2 i k \, _2F_2\left(\frac{3}{4},\frac{5}{4};\frac{3}{2},\frac{3}{2};-\frac{2 k^2}{\sigma ^2}\right)\right]$$

Comment: For the first one, i would have a look at $I'(k)$.
For the second one i would integrate the defining series of the Bessel function and see how far i get.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. However, differentiation under the integral sign doesn't seem to work. it results in products of gaussians by error functions that I don't think can be written in a closed form...

Does anyone know if the integrals I'm looking for have closed forms at all?

Comment: I'm quite sure that this products can be written in closed form. There are big collections of integrals involving the error function, just have a look if you find something. Maybe start here:
http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/jres/73B/jresv73Bn1p1_A1b.pdf

Comment: Again, thank you for the help, but I haven't been able to find anything yet. I'll keep working on it.

Answer (score 1):

> No full solutions, but some hints that might be helpful.

The first sum of integrals is really just one integral (the function is even):

$$\int_{-\infty}^{-a}\text{d}x \frac{1}{|x|}e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2\sigma^2}e^{i k |x|}+\int_a^{\infty}\text{d}x \frac{1}{|x|}e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2\sigma^2}e^{i k |x|}=2\int_a^{\infty}\text{d}x \frac{1}{|x|}e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2\sigma^2}e^{i k |x|}$$

Now, since $a>0$, we can get rid of the absolute value function:

$$I_1(k,\sigma,a)=2\int_a^{\infty}\text{d}x \frac{1}{x}e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2\sigma^2}e^{i k x}$$

$$\frac{\partial I_1(k,\sigma,a)}{\partial k}=2 i \int_a^{\infty} e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2\sigma^2}e^{i k x} \text{d}x$$

This integral can be expressed as error function of imaginary variable. I'm not sure how to work with it, so I'm leaving the rest up to you.

---

Now for the second integral.

$$I_2(k, \sigma)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\text{d}xJ_0(k\,x)e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2\sigma^2}e^{-i k x}$$

First, let's change the variable and parameter to simplify the expression $kx \to x$ and $\sigma / (\sqrt{2}~k)=\sigma$:

$$I_2(k, \sigma)=\frac{1}{k} \int_{0}^{\infty}J_0(x)e^{-x^2\sigma^2}e^{-i x}\text{d}x$$

Then the one way is to use the integral representation of the Bessel function:

$$J_0(x)=\frac{1}{\pi} \int_0^{\pi} \cos (x \cos t) dt=\frac{1}{2\pi}  \left( \int_0^{\pi} e^{i x \cos t} dt+\int_0^{\pi} e^{-i x \cos t} dt\right)$$

It's enough to consider one of two terms, another can be treated in the same way, then we get in our original integral:

$$\frac{1}{2\pi k} \int_0^{\pi} \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x^2\sigma^2}e^{-i x (1+\cos t)}\text{d}x ~\text{d}t$$

Now we complete the square:

$$-\sigma^2 x^2-i  (1+\cos t)x=-\sigma^2 \left(x+i \frac{1+\cos t}{2} \right)^2-\sigma^2 \frac{(1+\cos t)^2}{4}$$

However, this way we get error function of imaginary variable under the integral multiplied by the exponent with $-(1+\cos t)^2$ as an argument. So I think this just makes it worse. If we had $-\infty$ as a second limit the integral could be expressed as a series of modified Bessel functions, but in your case I don't see any way to simplify it.

Comment: Hi Yuriy,
Thanks! Your clue to solve the second integral looks like working. Inserting into Mathematica the expression $\frac{1}{2\pi k}\int_0^\pi dt\int_0^\infty dx e^{-x^2\sigma^2-ix(1+\cos t)}$ and performing first the integral in x, then the one in t, I get a closed-form expression in terms of generalyzed hypergeometric functions, namely I get $\frac{1}{2\pi k}\frac{\pi ^{3/2} \sigma  \, _2F_2\left(\frac{1}{4},\frac{3}{4};\frac{1}{2},1;-\frac{1}{\sigma ^2}\right)-i \pi  \, _2F_2\left(\frac{3}{4},\frac{5}{4};\frac{3}{2},\frac{3}{2};-\frac{1}{\sigma ^2}\right)}{2 \sigma ^2}$, thanks so much!

Comment: That's surprising, better check it numerically for several values of $\sigma$. Don't forget the second exponential term

Comment: Yes, it looks like it works for several values of $\sigma$, provided that you undo the change of variables $\sigma/(\sqrt{2}k)=\sigma$. Thank you so much again! :D